# AWS Amplify: How can I create nested subscription?

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify

I am developing app using AWS Amplify and using graphql API for serverless.
I have following tables:

- Users
- Pages
- UserPages - linking table joining users with pages they are following.
- Posts

Users can create and/or subscribe to Pages and create posts on pages.

I could use subscriptions so list of pages updated as soon as someone else creates new page and same with posts on pages.

But the problem I am having is how to create subscription so that I get notified about any new posts added to pages I am following.

How can I achieve this? Apologies if my question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You need the server to resolve the pages that a user follows, then return the posts from that page. In order to achieve that, you need to keep a global list of userIds that are subscribed to any page.
When a post changes, resolve which page this post belongs to. From there, resolve the users that belong to that page, then find out which one among them is online, and emit to them. An optimisation would be, when a post changes, get all the "online" users, then find out which one(s) among them belong to the page that that post has been posted to. This all depends on how many users you expect to be onlive vs how many pages you have...
See this [related anser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63048812/5927361) as well