# GraphQL & Using a nested subscribe function

Tags: javascript, graphql

I am writing a graphql subscriptions server. If I write a query it is no problem to have resolvers nested one within the other, so the query would look something like this:

```
query {
  messages {
    privateMessage {
      id
      message
      userId
    }
  }
}
```

So first the `messages` resolver is executed, then the `privateMessage` resolver is executed.
I would like to know if the same structure is achievable for subscriptions so it would look like this:

```
subscription {
  messages {
    privateMessage {
      id
      message
      userId
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the current root subscription schema I have:

```js
const RootSubscriptions = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootSubscriptions',
  fields: {
    privateMessage: {
      type: PrivateMessage.type,
      resolve: PrivateMessage.resolve,
      subscribe: PrivateMessage.subscribe,
    },
    flaggedMessage: {
      type: FlaggedMessage.type,
      resolve: FlaggedMessage.resolve,
      subscribe: FlaggedMessage.subscribe,
    },
    teamMessage: {
      type: TeamMessage.type,
      resolve: TeamMessage.resolve,
      subscribe: TeamMessage.subscribe,
    },
  },
})
```

I would like it to look like this:

```js
const RootSubscriptions = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'RootSubscriptions',
  fields: {
    messages: {
      type: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'MessagesSubType',
        fields: {
          privateMessage: {
            type: PrivateMessage.type,
            resolve: PrivateMessage.resolve,
            subscribe: PrivateMessage.subscribe,
          },
          flaggedMessage: {
            type: FlaggedMessage.type,
            resolve: FlaggedMessage.resolve,
            subscribe: FlaggedMessage.subscribe,
          },
          teamMessage: {
            type: TeamMessage.type,
            resolve: TeamMessage.resolve,
            subscribe: TeamMessage.subscribe,
          },
        }
      })
    }
  },
})
```

**EDIT END**

Problem is that I get the `messages` subscribe function to run but not the `privateMessage` subscribe function to run. Would love to know if it is possible and how to achieve it.
Since I'm writing it with node.js, I would appreciate an example in js, but any pointer to a solution would be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you completed any required websocket config?  Assuming that's accomplished, could you provide your schema defined for the subscription

Comment: @GregBrodzik thanks for your comment. I added the schema code. Yes the subscriptions in the current structure are working no problem, with a returned async-iterator, web-sockets and all that saga.

Comment: @U Rogel I typically use a pubsub instance to fire off at the correct time, generally in a mutation, and don't rely on subresolve for data structure.  However, if you were to return a messages type from a mutation, as in your query, the subresolver for private messages should be hit -- similar to your query.  So perhaps you could fire the pubsub from the context of the subresolver for private messages, using `obj`, and any additional data merged here to hydrate the return sub payload. You could use the `info` to determine whether you are firing in the correct context.

Comment: Have you considered creating a root subscription for messages, then providing the messagetype as a parameter?
That way, the subscription is for messages but within the resolver you switch case for each message type, in this case private, flagged and team

Comment: @Kisinga That is the most interesting comment I got on my question, so thanks! But that would still mean many iterations for none-relevant data. I wanted to try and skip those iterations by subscribing exactly to what I need.

Comment: I have posted this as an answer, maybe it will help someone else

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of how graphQl subscriptions work, you may have little luck with nested subscriptions. I've not found supporting documentation to support this, but in my own experimentations, I've not found this to work.
In this case, I would advice that you have a messages root subscription that expects parameters of the type of sucription, in this case an enum of either private, flagged or team message.
You can use switch case to determine the subscription and react accordingly.